# Concatenate variable into jQuery mobile pageinit page name

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

i was wondering if its possible to concatenate a variable into the page init call?

```
$("#Walk_"+walkId).on('pageinit', function(event){
    alert('haa');
});
```

I have tried the above code, however i haven't much luck. The variable comes from a foor loop located on another page, it is however set as a global variable, but it remains within the for loop and as such, its value is being overwritten however many times the loop iterates.

I was wondering if its even possible to do what i have shown above?

Thanks

EDIT:

The page creation from which i am trying to use the script above

```
    var makePage = $('<div data-role="page" id="Walk_'+walkId+'"><span class="walkID">'+walkId+'</span><div data-role="header"><a data-rel="back"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i></a><h1>'+walkTitle+'</h1></div><div class="mapDetails" style="width: 100%; height: 150px;"></div><script type="javascript" src="js/myRoutesDetail.js"></script></div>');

    makePage.appendTo($.mobile.pageContainer);
```

Comment: It should work.Is there an element with that Id `#Walk+...`?

Comment: there is a page with that name yes, the for loop generates and creates pages preappended with Walk then adds on the ID

Comment: try running your code with a breakpoint on that line and make sure walkId is defined

Comment: I've included the js file i'm trying to use for this particular page as part of the append to body, but i've just tried to run a console.log on the id itself to see if its even outputting and it isn't. Which can only mean the script file isn't actually being used

Comment: try putting concatenation js code inside `$(document).ready();` and see if it works.

Comment: No such luck i'm afraid @PrashantGhimire

I think the issue is that for some reason the `var makePage` line isn't really including the js file properly

Comment: Will setting var w/o script tag and adding `$.getScript("myRoutesDetail.js");` to load js instead work?

Comment: I've added that line in, as `<script>$.getScript("js/myRoutesDetail.js");</script>` instead of the `<script type="javascript" src="js/myRoutesDetail.js"></script>` and it now fires the javascript within myRoutesDetail.js on loading of the page that all the sub-pages are created instead of only the sub-pages

Comment: I'm wondering if theres something i could tie into this function?
https://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecreate/